# Any tool or utility to generate high speed logs

Tags: logging, hadoop, flume

We are working on Big Data project where we need to do sizing for Flume cluster.
Flume cluster will collect logs which will get generated at 15 mBps ( Mega Byte per seconds).
To simulate this situation, we need a utility/tool which can generate logs either at this speed(or scale down speed).
Let me know if there is any existing tool available.

Answer (score 0):

I've gotten good results from [Twitter Iago](https://github.com/twitter/iago).

- It reads a log to get sample data so you can send actual production data.
- It uses the Poisson/Exponential distribution so the time between requests is random - like production.
- It can send at a set rate and can use more load generation servers to get to that rate.